# Python code isnts working for negative indexing, and need to take user input as time

Tags: python, indexing, user-input

my code:

```
import csv
import math

forum = input("What was the name of the race?")
place = input("Where was the race?")
time = input("What was your time?")
length = int(input("What was the race length?"))
#pace = length/time

with open('times.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow([index+1, forum, place, time, length])

    #get the last index
    for line in f:
        index = int([line[0]-1])
```

the index is supposed to be a number showing which number race that was. the input as a time is to calculate the pace per mile, which cant be done with a string. and suggestions?

Comment: In your own words, what value do you expect `line` to have? Therefore, what value do you expect `line[0]` to have? Therefore, what value do you expect `line[0] - 1` to have? Therefore, what value do you expect `[line[0] - 1]` to have? `int([line[0]-1])`? In plain English, what do you think you are doing at each step of this expression? Also: *before* the `for` loop, where you have `thewriter.writerow([index+1, forum, place, time, length])`, where are you expecting the value of `index` to come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for line in f:
        index = int([line[0]]) - 1
```

You're trying to subtract number from a string. Also, you're using index before it is initialized.

```
import csv
import math

forum = input("What was the name of the race?")
place = input("Where was the race?")
time = input("What was your time?")
length = int(input("What was the race length?"))
#pace = length/time

index = 0
with open('times.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    #get the last index
    for line in f:
        index = int([line[0]-1])

    thewriter.writerow([index+1, forum, place, time, length])
```